# Загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: php

Реквестом получаю из формы кучу данных и циклами пихаю их по массивам для последующего добавления. изначально выглядит вот так

```
Array
(
    [lang] => en
    [ru] => Array
        (
            [user] => 1
            [name] => Название отеля:
            [rating] => 4
            [country] => 111
            [adress] => Адрес
            [description] => :asdasdad s d a
            [addVideos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3wesdfghn
                    [1] => r3r3f3f3
                )

            [addPhotos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Monika_Rouge.jpg
                    [1] => Monika_Brown.jpg
                )

            [element_property] => Array
                (
                    [RASPOLOGENIE] => Array
                        (
                            [246] => on
                            [247] => on
                        )

                    [TYPE_BUILD] => Array
                        (
                            [254] => on
                            [253] => on
                        )

                    [BEACH] => Array
                        (
                            [258] => on
                            [259] => on
                        )

                    [BEACH_SERVICE] => Array
                        (
                            [263] => on
                            [262] => on
                        )

                )

            [nomer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => asrtfg
                            [area] => werg
                            [smallpeople] => 2
                            [bigpeople] => 4
                            [description] => awesdrgtfhnbr345tyh
                            [kolvo] => Количество
                            [addPhotos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Monika_Black.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Название
                            [area] => fdsfdsfs
                            [smallpeople] => 2
                            [bigpeople] => 4
                            [description] => wertygh
                            [kolvo] => r3
                            [addPhotos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => akvarel.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => frewfrewfr
                            [area] => ewrwr
                            [smallpeople] => 2
                            [bigpeople] => 4
                            [description] => wrwr
                            [kolvo] => wrwrw
                            [addPhotos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Monika_Rouge.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Потом пытаюсь добавить все из массива nomer, в итоге этот массив хранит переменная $nomer

далее делаю:

```
    foreach ($nomer as $langfornomer){
        foreach ($langfornomer["addPhotos"] as $key => $filePath) {
        echo $filePath;
        if(is_uploaded_file($filePath))
        {
                move_uploaded_file($filePath, "/upload/".$filePath);
        } else {
                echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
        }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос. Как же всетаки сохранить файл на сервере и получить его путь? Сразу скажу enctype="multipart/form-data" написано :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_FILES
```

Не, не слышали?

Answer (score 1):

Как то странно вы загружаете фотки.

1. `<input type="file" ... />` есть такое ? Если да - какой у него name ?
2. `<form .... enctype="multipart/form-data">` есть такое ?

Comment: 1. input type="file" name="hotel[ru][addPhotos][]"
2. да

Comment: тогда var_dump($_FILES['hotel']['ru']['addPhotos']);

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['varNameInFormForInputTypeFile']['tmp_name'], "/upload/".$newFileName);
```